# What is the exact meaning of a strict fragment?

Tags: language-lawyer, uml, sequence-diagram

In a recent question I stumbled over [this example](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-combined-fragment.html#operator-strict):

[image]

The UML 2.5 spec says on p. 617:

> The InteractionOperatorKind strict designates that the CombinedFragment represents a strict sequencing between the behaviors of the operands. The semantics of strict sequencing defines a strict ordering of the operands on the first level within the CombinedFragment with interactionOperator strict. Therefore OccurrenceSpecifications within contained CombinedFragment will not directly be compared with other OccurrenceSpecifications of the enclosing CombinedFragment.

Well, that leaves me with question marks. What would be the difference in the above if you don't have the fragment and only the messages? They would appear in this (strict) order anyway. Right? Or is it like: do the first, if that fails the 2nd and if that fails the 3rd? Probably not! But what is it then?

Comment: Good question. The language is odd, but I think it means that the caller must make these calls only in this order.

Comment: @JimL. But that's already expressed with the order of the messages anyway. Good to see that I'm not the only one being puzzled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are no reply messages modeled, it is not specified, whether the sender waits for them, before sending the next message. Without the `strict` operator it would therefore be possible that the reception of `search_google()` is *after* the execution in reaction to `search_yahoo()`. With the operator, the occurrences in each operand will all occur before the occurences in the next operand.

The example would be less confusing, had they used asynchroneous messages.

Of course the question is, how is it ensured that only the trace defined by the `strict` operator can happen. In the case of asynchroneous messages the sender has no way of knowing, whether `search_google()` finished executing. I think other traces are possible, but the current diagram describes what happens after the combined fragment, if the strict ordering is observed.

The sentence on *"Occurrence Specifications within contained CombinedFragment"* refers to nested CombinedFragments:

[image: sequence diagram with nested CombinedFragments]

The nested CombinedFragment `opt` doesn't obey the strict operator. Therefore, `m1` can happen before or after `m3`. I don't have a good example where this is useful, but it's how the specification defines it.

Comment: To my understanding a synchronous message is one that waits for the sender to complete the service in contrast to an asynchronous one. Am I mistaken? In that case I don't see any necessity for a strict fragment. In case of asynchronous messages, to me, it would seem to be more appropriate to use synch messages in such a case.

Comment: @qwerty_so Yes, the sender waits. But while waiting, it can do additional things, like sending the next synchroneous message. If the behavior of the sender is described by an activity, it could have a fork node with two outgoing controlflows.  -  Of course, very often we omit the reply message for brevity. We should then document somewhere the convention, that a missing reply message is thought of following immediately below the synchroneous message. The specification doesn't say this.  -  Synchroneous messages are better here? Well, to explain `strict` they only add confusion.

Comment: Maybe I'm dumb, but I still don't get it. What especially confuses me is _will not directly be compared_ in the spec. Compare what to what? Further: _while wating_ ... I can't do anything since I'm waiting.

Comment: I can do other things while I'm waiting. It just depends on my multitasking abilities. Of course we could limit the behaviors to single threads. But the specification does allow multiple threads.

Comment: I added an explanation for _"will not directly be compared"_

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but - phew - that makes it even more unclear. Why can now m1 happen **after** m3??

Comment: All events are on different lifelines. And even though m1 is indirectly included in a strict sequencing operand, it is exempt from its stipulations because it is not directly included.

Comment: Oh, I see. This will take me one step further. Though I'm not at the end of the tunnel. Maybe tomorrow :-)

Comment: Chap, 17.6.4.7 also has this quirky definition (who wrote that?). So the Strict is only about nested fragments, right? I still don't get for what this should be good for.

Comment: Me neither. I never use this.

Comment: You should have said this in your answer ;-)